# How to export MySQL image blobs into a PDF document?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, tcpdf

I am currently using the [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org) library to create PDFs on the fly.  As part of my application, I store multiple image files (png, jpg, gif) in a MySQL database, in blob format.  I'd like to use the TCPDF [Image()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352) function to place these images into a PDF file, each on a separate page.  Is there an easy way to take the blob content for multiple entries in my database and place them into a PDF file?  I am not tied to TCPDF if there is a better way to do this.  Please help!

Answer (score -1):

You do it like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT pdf FROM pdfs WHERE transaction = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($pdfcontent);
while($stmt->fetch()){
     header("Content-Length: " . strlen($pdfcontent) );
     header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="YourPDF.pdf"');
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
     echo $pdfcontent;
}
```